# how to install Components (client tools connectivity and Client tools backwords Compatibility) in sql server 2022

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I'm installing SQL Server 2022.

When I install SQL server 2022, I cannot find the components below in the feature selection:

- Client tools connectivity
- Client tools backwards Compatibility
- Client Tools SDK

I need these components for my application.
How to install components?